# "heroku run fileName" after grunt build

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, heroku, yeoman

To learn more about heroku scheduling I read [this](http://www.spacjer.com/blog/2014/02/10/defining-node-dot-js-task-for-heroku-scheduler/) post and built the app described in it. The key part of this post was when I was able to `heroku run numCheck` and the [code within the numCheck file](https://github.com/andrewscheuermann/scheduler-tester/blob/master/bin/numCheck) executed. After testing that `heroku run numCheck` worked I was able to schedule regularly occurring events in Heroku just fine.

I used [yo angular-fullstack](https://www.npmjs.org/package/generator-angular-fullstack) to create my app, [Angel Insights](http://www.angelinsights.herokuapp.com) and it's functional. However I want to add in heroku scheduling capabilities but I'm getting stuck. My problem is that I cannot run `heroku run refresh` in the Dist folder after I've run `grunt build`. Here's what I've tried specifically...

1. Added bin/refresh before Grunt build (refresh code below)
2. Added bin/refresh directly into the Dist folder after grunt build
3. Tried heroku run anyFile after git push heroku master with both attempts

````````

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var sendgrid  = require('sendgrid')(
  process.env.SENDGRID_USERNAME,
  process.env.SENDGRID_PASSWORD
);

var num1 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100);
var num2 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100);
var comparator;

if (num1 > num2) {
    comparator = "greater than";
} else if (num1 < num2) {
    comparator = "less than";
} else {
    comparator = "equal to";
}

sendgrid.send({
    to: 'andrewscheuermann@gmail.com',
    from: 'scheduler@tester.com',
    subject: 'Num1 v Num2',
    text: (num1 + ' is ' + comparator + " " + num2 + ".")
  }, function(err, json) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
}
```

I'm really stuck and any insights are extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the angular generators you have to be careful about it overwriting the `dist` directory.  Each time you `grunt build` you're going to start with a mostly clean `dist` dir.

The steps should be something like:

1. `grunt build`
2. `cp refresh dist/refresh`
3. `cd dist && git commit`
4. `git push heroku master`
5. `heroku run refresh`

The main missing step being that you have to commit the copied file into `dist` after you copy it, otherwise heroku won't get it.  You can always do `heroku run ls` or `heroku run bash` to see if your file is there.

After that works, you should look at your `Gruntfile.js` to make sure that `refresh` is copied there each time, you probably want to look at the `copy` task.

Comment: This was correct with one minor tweak needed. The refresh file needed to be put copied into a `dist/bin` directory. Then it works great. Thanks for the answer David!